# Sharepoint 2010 editing WebSiteTemplate

Tags: web-template

In sharepoint 2010 I create a new Web with a WebSiteTemplate. The template was created by the export-function of an existing WebSiteCollection. The new web looks similar to the other exepting the Content-Editor WebPart on the default.aspx
The site on which I exported the template doesn't contains the Content-Editor WebPart.
Is there a possibility to edit the exported template to remove the WebPart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a little update/resolution. The exported Web can be imported in solutions.
Add->new Project->Import SharePoint Solution Package. After a few additional clicks in the wizard and the exported web is ready to work.